# install flex builder with eclipse ubuntu 9.10

Tags: eclipse, flexbuilder

I have the linux alpha version of flex builder installed in /opt/flex and eclipse was installed with synaptic package manager into /usr/lib/eclipse.  It looks like eclipse is not aware of flex, since when I attempt to create a new file with eclipse I don't see flex builder as an option.

Answer (score 1):

In the release notes, found at http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/releasenotes.html#overview, there is the script file Adobe_Flex_builder.sh in the install directory.  Running that should start Eclipse preconfigured with the Flex Builder plugin.

Comment: Looks like I got it working.  I didn't install flex builder properly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Adobe has decided not to support Flex Builder for linux. Have a look at this -> http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/